# Contour plot showing no result

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour, contourf

I was just wondering I have the following code:

```
[r,R] = meshgrid(2:0.01:10,-4:0.01:4);
Z=(((R).^2)-1 );
   A=2+ (R.*(r+r^-1));
   B=sqrt(Z).*(r-r^-1);
   C=((r+r^-1)./(sqrt(Z))).*acoth(A./B);
    figure
contourf(r,R,C);
    h=colorbar;
    set(get(h,'ylabel'),'string','\gamma P_P L')
    xlabel('$r$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',18)
    ylabel('$D \over 2\sqrt{M}$','Interpreter','latex','FontSize',18)
```

I just get for A and B all answers infinite but I am not sure why?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the dot.  `r^-1` is the same as `inv(r)`.  And since all of `r`'s rows are the same as the first, it's reduced-row echelon form will have nearly all zeros, and the inverse will have infinite values.  I believe you meant

```
A=2+ (R.*(r+r.^-1));
```

or, more clearly in my opinion,

```
A=2+ (R.*(r+ 1./r));
```

and so on for the rest of the `r^-1`.

Comment: Thank you very much I was just wondering if I can impose a condition on my function within a contour plot

Comment: @AbedLibnanHaidar It depends what you mean by that.  Could you be more specific and I'll see if I can find a question to help you?